# google map lat lon not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get Google map lat and lon from my link id value id by its not working.id always get text value not id value

my code

```
var map;
$(document).ready(function(){
    // listen for clicks on that element
    $('.android').on('click', function(){
        // get the data
        var lat = $(this).attr('id1'),
            lon = $(this).attr('id2');
        // send the data to you function. There are 10 other ways to do this but this'll work.
        initialize(lat, lon);
    });

}); 
function initialize(lat, lon) {




var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      map: map
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


<a class="android" data-toggle="modal" id1="'.$cd[$i][9].'" id2="'.$cd[$i][10].'" href="#myMapModal" class="btn btn-info">View On Map</a>
```

but always `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);` get text lat lon but not any value.

Answer (score 0):

If lat and lon end up as text representation of the desired values then you should parse for floats.

```
var lat = parseFloat( $(this).attr('id1') ),
    lon = parseFloat( $(this).attr('id2') );
```

I've zero knowledge of Android and I'm unaware of what '.$cd[$i][9].' gets as a value, but in your case it's probably not a number.